# Java IOException error

Tags: java

Consider the following code snippet:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(. . .);
. . .
if (in.hasNext())
{
   throw new IOException("End of file expected");
}
```

Two of the answers are:

a. The program will display the message "End of file expected" if there is data left in the input when the if statement is executed. Incorrect

b. The program will throw an exception if there is data left in the input when the if statement is executed. Correct

I chose "a". Is this not true? Are both of these statements not true? Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you actually executed the code? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program may or may not print the message "End of file expected". If the exception thrown is never caught, then the program will terminate and, along with the stack trace, the message will be printed. However, the exception might be caught further up in the stack (i.e. by a method that called the method containing the code in question), in which case the message may or may not be printed out, depending on what the method does with the exception.

If you're only given the code above and no other context, then the only thing that is certain is that an exception will be thrown. Anything else will depend on the context of the code in the program.

Comment: So, based upon the code snippet, the exception is not technically caught, correct? Meaning termination and printing?

Comment: Yes -- in just the segment of code given, it is thrown, but not caught. It could be surrounded by a `catch` block, or the method it's in could have a `throws` clause, but just in the segment there's nothing that prevent a termination.

Answer (score 1):

b is definitley true, a is not entirely true.
It's quite obvious why b is true since the throw statement throws the exception if the conditions are met.
However, a is only true if the exception is not caught and the default exception handler prints the exception's message.
However, the throw statement techincally doesn't display anything.
If you catch the exception or set another uncaught exception handler for this thread, your exception's message might never be displayed anywhere.
That's why only b is **certainly** correct.